# Java String.valueOf(null) throws NPE, but Object a = null; String.valueOf(a) returns 'null'

Tags: java, string

Is there a logical language-design-type explanation for the following behaviour (Java 7 and I suspect earlier editions as well):

```
    Object  a = null;
    String as = String.valueOf(a);              // as is assigned "null"
    System.out.println(as+":"+as.length());     // prints: "null:4"
    System.out.println ( String.valueOf(null)); // NPE
```

Comment: Java 1.6 does throw a nullpointer in eclipse

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In statement `System.out.println(String.valueOf(null));` there is a call of method `public static String valueOf(char data[])`, which source code is as follows:

```java
public static String valueOf(char data[]) {
  return new String(data);
}
```

That is why you get **NPE**

On the other hand, in statement `Object  a = null; String as = String.valueOf(a);` there is a calls of method `public static String valueOf(Object obj)`, which source code is as follows:

```java
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

That is why you get **"null"** instead of **NPE**

---

A bit of theory from Java Language Specification: [15.12.2.5 Choosing the Most Specific Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.5)

*If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the **most specific** method is chosen.*

A `char[]` is of type `Object`, but not all `Object` are of type `char[]`. Type `char[]` is **more specific** than Object and as described in the Java Language Specification, the `String.valueOf(char[])` overload is chosen in this case.

**EDIT**

It is also worth mentioning what [Ian Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592139/ian-roberts) mentioned (in his comment below):

> It's important to note that it's a compile error if there is no single
>   overloading that is more specific than all the others - if there were
>   a `valueOf(String)` method as well as `valueOf(Object)` and
>   `valueOf(char[])` then a call to the untyped `String.valueOf(null)`
>   would be ambiguous

Comment: It's important to note that it's a compile error if there is no single overloading that is more specific than all the others - if there were a `valueOf(String)` method as well as `valueOf(Object)` and `valueOf(char[])` then a call to the untyped `String.valueOf(null)` would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 15):

The first invocation is to `String#valueOf(Object)`, the second is to `String#valueOf(char[])`

The overloaded method is chosen according to the argument's **static type**, this is why the first works and the seconds get an NPE.

If you invoke `System.out.println ( String.valueOf((Object)null));` it will work

Comment: +1. A term worth mentioning: The overloaded method is chosen according to the argument *static type*.

Comment: @amit Added it to the answer, worth mentioning indeed.

Answer (score 7):

That's because of this code in `String` class:

```
public static String valueOf(char data[]) {
return new String(data);
}
```

Your code (which throws `NullPointerException`) calls the above-mentioned method and, thus, the `data` field is `null`. In fact, this call is thrown by the `String` class on constructor.

Using JDK 6, the exception is as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:177)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2840)
    at org.bfs.data.SQLTexter.main(SQLTexter.java:364)
```

As for your line:

```
System.out.println(as+":"+as.length());     // prints: "null:4"
```

This works as the below method is called:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Obviously, `a` is of type `Object` so the `String.valueOf(Object)` method is called.

If you specifically want to call `String.valueOf(Object obj)` method, typecast your null as follows:

```
System.out.println (String.valueOf((Object)null));
```

You're experiencing method overloading (where there are several method with the same name and method signature, but have different method parameters). In your case (where NPE occurs), the JVM determines which method to call based on the **most specific** static type. If the type is declared, then the most specific method is the method with the same parameter type of the declared variable, else, a *most specific method* rule is used by the JVM to find which method to invoke.

I hope this helps.

Comment: How is the first `String.valueOf(...)` call different than  the second?

Comment: @Kevin, I've updated my code and see what `valueOf()` method it calls.